# How I can edit next cell in DataGrid after the error?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a problem with the DataGrid, which marks the border in red, incorrectly entered the cell. I read that it is useful to apply

```
<!------------------------     XAML     ------------------------------->

    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
      <Style>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
         <!-- no red border round cell-->
      </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>

<!------------------------     XAML     ------------------------------->
```

That's right border is white, but I still can not edit the next cell in the DataGrid. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think the correct solution would be to cancel the edit of the faulted row, but right now I don't have time for a fully tested answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this follows MVVM structure and if it repeats multiple times then your best bet would be to have your own `DataGrid` which inherits from another `DataGrid`. then you would override `OnCellEditEnding` method like:

`public class myDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnCellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}`

Or Even a crazier way would be like this:

```
 protected override void OnCanExecuteBeginEdit(System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var hasCellValidationError = false;
    var hasRowValidationError = false;
    const BindingFlags bindingFlags =
        BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
    var cellError= this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("HasCellValidationError", bindingFlags);
    var rowError = this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("HasRowValidationError", bindingFlags);

    if (cellError != null) 
        hasCellValidationError = (bool) cellErrorInfo.GetValue(this, null);
    if (rowError != null)
        hasRowValidationError = (bool) rowErrorInfo.GetValue(this, null);

    base.OnCanExecuteBeginEdit(e);
    if ((!e.CanExecute && hasCellValidationError) || (!e.CanExecute && hasRowValidationError))
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```